# How to manually render a Django template for an inlineformset_factory with can_delete = True / False

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I have an inlineformset with a custom Modelform. So it looks something like this:

```
MyInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(MyMainModel, MyInlineModel, form=MyCustomInlineModelForm)
```

I am rendering this inlineformset manually in a template so that I have more control over widgets and javascript. So I go in a loop like `{% for form in myformset.forms %}` and then manually render each field as described on this page http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template

The formset has `can_delete = True` or `can_delete = False` depending on whether the user is creating new objects or editing existing ones.

Question is, how do I manually render the can_delete checkbox?

Comment: Also on http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/86def8e3cb40a7bc/

Comment: see also the formset docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-the-formset-in-the-template

Answer (score 5):

inlineformset_factory marks can_delete=True, and I don't know if you can change it, but, you can render it with "form.DELETE"